# How design a controller action to respond to guess and authorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an action in my controller design for users already register in my system:

```
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult getUserData()
 {
      string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
      return getDataFromDB(UserID);
 }
```

And is working OK. Also redirect to the `LOGIN` page if you arent authenticated yet.

But I also want to have a dummy function `getFakeData()` for anonymous users visiting the page so they can see the like a demo of the page.

Where should I put the validation to see if user is authenticated or not and change the behaviour?

1. On the webpage I can set the dataUrl based if user is authenticated. I can make a separated function without `[Authorize]` tag

   ```
   @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {
        dataUrl = '=/Project/Controller/getUserData'
   } else {
        dataUrl = '=/Project/Controller/getFakeData'    
   }
   ```
2. Or can I do it on the same action controller and checking if user is authenticated or not? But not sure is that is possible.
3. Or is a better way to do it?

Comment: Another option would be to have a link on the Login page that redirects to a method that generates the 'fake' data (which is marked with `[AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That could work, how I check in that function if user is anonymous or already athenticated?

Comment: The user would not have been redirected to the login page if they were already authenticated (unless they navigated directly to the login page)

Comment: The user would not have been redirected to the login page if they were already authenticated (unless they navigated directly to the login page)

Comment: Could just be a simple _To see a demo without logging in, click here_ message on the page (or even on your home page)

Comment: If I were you I'd develop my own authorization attribute, and would customize it by assigning roles including anonymous. Then I could furnish the result in accordance with the access rights.

Comment: Why don't you just create a guest user in your database ? Then set the option to login as a user or as a guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this but here is my recommendation

```
// For ASP.Net MVC 5 simply inherit from AuthorizationAttribute and override the methods.
public class AccessControlAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly Roles role;
    public AccessControlAttribute(Roles role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    private Boolean AuthorizationCore(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
        var username = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["loginCookie_username"];
        var password = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["loginCookie_password"];
        if (role == Roles.FakeFullAccess) {
            username = "FAKE";
            goto final;
        }
        //In ASP.Net MVC 5 use Ninject for dependency injection and get the service using : [NinjectContext].GetKernel.Get<DbContext>();
        DbContext db = (DbContext) context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(DbContext));
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            var findUser = db.Set<Login>().Find(username);
            if (findUser != null && findUser.Password.Equals(password) && findUser.RoleId == (int)role) {
                goto final;
            }
        }
        return false;
        final: {
            context.HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username));
            return true;
        }   
    }
    private void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
        context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new {
            area = "",
            controller = "",
            action = ""
        });
    }        
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (AuthorizationCore(context))
        {
            // If using a combination of roles, you have to unmask it
            if (role == Roles.FakeFullAccess) {
                context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Render", "FakeAccess");
            }
            else if (role == Roles.Admin)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Render", "AdminAccess");
            }
        }
        else {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
        }
    }

}
[Flags]
public enum Roles
{
    FakeFullAccess = 0, 
    ReadOnly = 1,
    Admin = 2,
    Supervisor = 1 << 2,
    AnotherRole = 1 << 3
}
```

in your view you can read the added header and customize the view (in ASP.Net Core there's no access to ControllerContext and ViewBag, if using ASP.Net MVC 5 you don't need to use the header trick)

```
// For ASP.Net MVC 5 use the ViewBag or ViewData
@Html.Partial(HttpContext.Request.Header["Render"])
//Assuming this renders the menu with proper functions.
```

Now you have fully customizable role based authentication system with fake access for testing.

**Update:**
To consume the attribute do the following

```
[AccessControl(Role.Admin)]
public TestController: Controller {
    ...
}
// Dedicated for testing
[AccessControl(Role.FakeAccess)]
public PreviewController: TestCoontroller{}
```

You can also combine roles if required like `[AccessControl(Role.FakeAccess | Role.ReadOnly)]` but you have to implement an unmasking method.

Comment: In what stage you assign fake role to anonymous user?

Comment: at the beginning, please pay attention to the `uthorizationCore` method and goo 3 lines below.

Comment: You compare `role == Roles.FakeFullAccess` but dont see where you initialize role?

Comment: Again, in this scenerio what make one anonymous user have `FakeAccess` Role? in the web? the cookie?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Since the approach (as you asked) is attribute based, it is statically defined for each controller, method that you wanna control based on access rights. The actual role associated to the use is not stored anywhere but the Db and it will be checked upon each request. You can cache it in order to reduce stress on the Db Server but if security is of great importance it would be better not to cache it.

Comment: I understand some thing but dont have a depth knowledge of what is going on, most of my login code was autogenerated and I just configure a few things. I probably need a basic tutorial .

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: It is very simple, please do not look at the length of the code. I personally believe that customized security layers are more secure than built-in ones, so I'd always rather customize them as I want. This the customized version of the built-in `AuthorizationAttribute` which is sealed in Asp.Net Core. You can refer to the MSDN to see how exactly the `AuthorizationAttribute` works. Though I'd be more than happy to help if you have any question.

Comment: Right now I have a page to CRUD user/roles and work ok. Can secure pages, assign permission to do some things or forbid others. But in this case dont know how I will ask for anonyomous.roles because he never login. That is what the solution I put In my quesiton is based on the asp page.

Comment: The anonymous users should have limited rights. So you have to decorate only and only those APIs to which they can have access with `[AllowAnonymous]` or `[AccessControl(Role.Anonymous)]` as in my example. It is really easy, if you have further questions, we can move to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127024/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-transcendent).